# How to delete all files with .mp3 extension?

Tags: .net, vb.net

I have an external hard disk drive for data backup purpose. Now I want to delete all mp3 files in that drive. How do I do it?

NOTE: The mp3 files are contained within many nested folders. For example, `K:\(artist name)\(album name)\`mp3 files

Update: I tried using `system.io.directory.getallfiles()`, but my mp3 files are contained in many many folders. My current approach is not working

Update: I want to create a utility application (in winform) that can delete specific file extension, i.e. `.mp3`

Comment: Use search in Explorer for *.mp3, then Select All and Delete? :) Provide code that you have tried to write to do that and we help to resolve whats wrong in it.

Comment: What have you tried? What didn't work? Are you actually asking a programming question here?

Comment: command line execute "DEL *.mp3"?

Comment: yor question have .net and vb.net tags... it it because yo are asking us how to do it from vb.net?
So or you posted a question without caring at all or you putted random tag and yo are on the worng forum since yor question is not about programming at all!

Comment: @archer: I have more than 600GB mp3 files, and using `search in explorer` is not doable

Comment: @Stefano: Grr..., I need to delete it via code, that is vb.net code

Comment: @Prema, do you need to write function inside application that will remove them? Or you just need to remove them? If second - use Total Commander instead then :) If first - provide your attempts and we help to fix it.

Comment: @Oded: I tried using system.io.directory.getallfiles(), but my mp3 files are contained in many many folders. My current approach is not working

Comment: @archer: Yes, I need a function within a winform application to delete the mp3 files

Comment: It is still not clear if you simply want to remove all files (which can be done in a command window), or write an application that can do so.

Comment: @Oded: I want to create a utility application (in winform) that can delete specific file extension.

Comment: Then please edit your question and clarify that this is exactly what you are trying to do.

Comment: @ Oded: Actually I want to upload the screenshot of my application. But my reputation is under 10, so I can't upload it

Answer (score 2):

I'm not familiar with VB.NET, so can only point what functions to use:

- to find all files including subdirectories use [`GetFiles`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143316.aspx) with
  [`SearchOption.AllDirectories`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143448.aspx)
- then go through all returned files and call [`File.Delete`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.io.file.delete.aspx)
  on each.

It would be something like this (sorry if have some mistakes):

```
Try
    For Each f In Directory.GetFiles("F:\", "*.mp3", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
        File.Delete(f)
    Next
Catch ex As UnauthorizedAccessException
End Try
```

Read about exceptions on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk6t46tz%28v=vs.71%29.aspx).

Comment: I need to search the entire drive's folders, can this line `Directory.GetFiles("F:\", "*.mp3", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
` achieve it?

Comment: @Prema, yes. It will return all .mp3 files in F:\ and all subdirectories recursively. Use provided links to MSDN to read more detailed information how functions work.

Comment: While in theory yes that should work out, I'd just like to say: don't call Directory.GetFiles over and over in loop, store its result in a String array and iterate over that. Also if you are running on an NTFS volume, you're going to run into Access Denied errors for trying to traverse "System Volume Information" system folder (which GetFiles will try to browse when you run at root). Best not to run at root or traverse the folder structure yourself and handle the exception or don't iterate over it. GetFiles will not let you work through this if you are running at root level.

Comment: @Maverik, good remarks. Also will add, that on directories with NTFS symbolic links it can cause infinite loop. But provided code is just a point to start. For problem with system folders: need to catch `UnauthorizedAccessException`.

Comment: @Prema, what help are you waiting? Nobody understand. From you question and comments I gave you code. What need else?

Comment: @archer: As said by Maverik, your solution got problem. I'm asking Maverik to provide better solution.

Comment: @Maverik The code is calling `Directory.GetFiles` exactly once!

Comment: @Konrad Rudolph: Oh you 6 digit reputation user, please offer your KING's answer!

Comment: @Prema Where is the problem? The solution works, minus one small syntax error which I’ve fixed.

Comment: @Konrad Rudolph: Here is the problem as indicated by Maverik `if you are running on an NTFS volume, you're going to run into Access Denied errors for trying to traverse "System Volume Information" system folder (which GetFiles will try to browse when you run at root)`

Comment: @Prema, how about to read more attentive other comments? I have already mentioned, that you just need to catch exceptions. If you don't know what is it, its good for you to start learning. In other way, provided code corresponds to your question.

Comment: @Konrad Rudolph I was under the impression that Loop evaluates GetFiles result every time it pulls a result from collection that is returned by GetFiles. Perhaps I've just learned something about internal working O.O (thank you in that case!)

Comment: @archer: Ok, can you perfect your answer and eliminate the `potential` problem as indicated by Maverik?

Comment: @Prema, have read about exceptions in vb.net and added catching. Should work.

Answer (score 1):

Ok considering the long chain of comments that is pursuing, I've decided to write a snippet in VS and here is my working code. Hope this solves your problem. Again, bear in mind that this does not deal with symbolic link looping but I strongly doubt you'll have those in your folders; otherwise time to read!

```
For Each folder In Directory.GetDirectories("D:\")
    Try
        For Each filePath In Directory.GetFiles(folder, "*.mp3", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
            'I'll just print the mp3 file found but of course you can delete it in your folder
            Debug.WriteLine(String.Format("{0}", filePath))

            'File.Delete(filePath)
        Next

    Catch ex As UnauthorizedAccessException
     'Report your exception here if you need to. I'm just ignoring it
    End Try
Next
```

Comment: Is the loop through `Directory.GetDirectories("D:\")` necessary? Why not just to call `Directory.GetFiles("D:\", ...)`?

Comment: @archer work-around for UnauthorizedAccessException on system folders. If you do a blanket try catch on GetFiles directly at root, it will exit GetFiles, fall into Catch block, then fall out of try block and you will have nothing in variable leaving you with NullReferenceException if you try to use the variable.

Comment: @Maverik, OK, agree. But your solution will fall too, if I have folder somewhere inside and don't have permissions to enter it (for example, "C:\Users\Admin\...")

Comment: @archer Agreed. That did cross my mind, but again I doubt he will have permissions locking down his mp3 folders. If he does, time to read and learn :)

Comment: @Maverik: Another flawed answer. Can you perfect your flawed answer?

Comment: @Perma No sorry mate, we've spent enough time on this and you really need to read now and show us some real code that you have done with exact errors. Just telling us we have a flawed answer really doesn't do anybody any good when we don't know what you're doing and what is wrong.

Comment: @Maverik: Your code is flawed as indicated by archer `your solution will fall too, if I have folder somewhere inside and don't have permissions to enter it (for example, "C:\Users\Admin\...")`

Comment: @Perma then you already have answer to that too and I'll paste it again: `That did cross my mind, but again I doubt he will have permissions locking down his mp3 folders. If he does, time to read and learn`

Comment: @Maverik: Perfect your flawed answer not just for me but to other future visitors.

Comment: @Perma most people here actually read all answers. If you did too, you'd actually find almost all the cases covered between the four answers. SO is here to provide help, which we've done. Now you need to do the homework of putting it all together and solving your problem.

Combine martins answer with mine or archers answer and you have a solution that covers the 'flaw' that either of our answers have. How to combine, I'll leave it as an exercise for the reader!

Comment: This comment for all future visitors. This is a flawed answer. Please don't use it.

Answer (score 1):

```
Imports System
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Collections

Public Class RecursiveFileProcessor

Public Overloads Shared Sub Main(ByVal args() As String)
    Dim path As String
    For Each path In args
        If File.Exists(path) Then
            ' This path is a file.
            ProcessFile(path)
        Else
            If Directory.Exists(path) Then
                ' This path is a directory.
                ProcessDirectory(path)
            End If
        End If
    Next path
End Sub 'Main


' Process all files in the directory passed in, recurse on any directories 
' that are found, and process the files they contain.
Public Shared Sub ProcessDirectory(ByVal targetDirectory As String)
    Dim fileEntries As String() = Directory.GetFiles(targetDirectory)
    ' Process the list of files found in the directory.
    Dim fileName As String
    For Each fileName In fileEntries
        ProcessFile(fileName)

    Next fileName
    Dim subdirectoryEntries As String() = Directory.GetDirectories(targetDirectory)
    ' Recurse into subdirectories of this directory.
    Dim subdirectory As String
    For Each subdirectory In subdirectoryEntries
        ProcessDirectory(subdirectory)
    Next subdirectory

End Sub 'ProcessDirectory

' Insert logic for processing found files here.
Public Shared Sub ProcessFile(ByVal path As String)
    if path.EndsWith(".mp3") then DeleteFile(path)
End Sub 'ProcessFile
End Class 'RecursiveFileProcessor
```

Comment: Your last line of code needs to be added to rest of code block. I'd edit it for you but I can't do less than 6 non-space characters edit apparently. Also you need to deal with the main problem of having access denied errors when traversing system folder at root as per comment chains in other answers

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a class for you but in c# :) You can easily convert this to VB.net

```
Imports System.IO

Module Module1

Sub Main()

    Dim d As New DirectoryInfo("d:\")

    deleteMp3File(d)


End Sub


Public Sub deleteMp3File(ByVal directory As DirectoryInfo)
    For Each f As FileInfo In directory.GetFiles()
        If f.Extension.ToLower().Equals("mp3") Then
            deleteFile(f.FullName)
        End If
    Next

    Dim obj As DirectoryInfo() = directory.GetDirectories()

    If obj IsNot Nothing AndAlso obj.Count() > 0 Then
        For Each d As DirectoryInfo In obj
            deleteMp3File(d)
        Next
    End If
End Sub

Public Sub deleteFile(ByVal path As String)
    File.Delete(path)
End Sub


End Module
```

Comment: thanks but not useful to me because I'm new to programming and only a beginner in vb.net

Comment: @Gaurav, read comments to my answer. The same problems.

Comment: copy each method to http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/vb-to-csharp/#convert-code and you can convert it to vb.net

Comment: @archer: Don't be sad. Your answer is flawed as indicated by Maverik

Comment: @Perma His answer isn't really flawed as it is meant to get you started, not to do the code for you. I just pointed out something that you learn from experience to save you some time.